# Picker view : I want data in picker view 2 change with picker view 1 when select data from picker view 1

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have some question about picker view  I have two picker view
picker view 1 = getpPlandateDCPlanData
picker view 2 = getpShipmentDCPlanData

I want data in picker view 2 change with  picker view 1 when select data from picker view 1

```
var getpPlandateDCPlanData = ["20190118","20190119"]
var getpShipmentDCPlanData = ["4505023244","4505023274"]
```

```
//  Picker view function
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerview1 {
            return self.getpPlandateDCPlanData.count
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerview2{
            return self.getpShipmentDCPlanData.count
        }
        return 1

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerview1{
            return getpPlandateDCPlanData[row]
            //return self.convertToString(dateString: getpPlandateDCPlanData[row], formatIn: "yyyyMMdd", formatOut: "MMM dd, yyyy")
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerview2{
            return getpShipmentDCPlanData[row]
        }
        return nil;

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //if getpPlandateDCPlanData.count > 0 && getpPlandateDCPlanData.count >= row && getpShipmentDCPlanData.count >= row {
        if getpPlandateDCPlanData.count >= row && getpShipmentDCPlanData.count >= row {
            if pickerView == pickerview1 {
                getpPlanDatePickerView.text = getpPlandateDCPlanData[row]
                print("PlanDatePickerView ==> \(getpPlandateDCPlanData)")
            }
            else if pickerView == pickerview2 {
                getpShipmentPickerView.text = getpShipmentDCPlanData[row]
                print("ShipmentPickerView ==> \(getpShipmentDCPlanData)")
            }//if
        }//if
    }
```

Comment: Ok but how? Since I see no attempt in your code to solve this it is really hard to understand how and what you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there in your existing code - just use the `didSelectRow` method to detect a change in `pickerView1` and then set the row in `pickerView2`.  I've added a trivial example below that just swaps the rows in pickerView 2 to the opposite of pickerView1.

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      if pickerView === pickerView1 {
         switch row {
         case 0: pickerView2.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
         case 1: pickerView2.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
         default: break
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: OP wants the data to change and not the selection. With your solution, is the second picker view even needed?

Comment: In my example no the second one is not needed but I read the question differently to you, and was answering it in the context given.  Your interpretation would make more sense 

Comment: Yes, clarification is needed

Comment: @flanker I copy your code and test in my application code not working, i'm not sure

Comment: @Nardanong.s as per the comments, you need to clarify what you are trying to do.  The above code is an example of the technique - _if_ it's what you're trying to achieve then you'd need to apply the technique to your app, not just copy and paste.